# How can I make a Git commit using MingW64?

Tags: git, github

Currently trying to use Git w/Github and MingW64, but can't seem to make a commit - when the prompt to write the commit message comes up, nothing I do enters the commit message. Pressing enter just creates new lines and attempting to type something often just messes up the commit status message.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/493511448639832085/917962883164409856/unknown.png

It's extra annoying as I've managed to make the commit via the GUI, but I want to master using the terminal. =/ I am confused as heck.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have ended up in vi, which is the default editor in Unix and Unix-like environments, and the default for Git if you haven't specified anything else.  Vi (and Vim, which is probably the vi variant you're using) is very powerful, but it has a significant learning curve, and as the Git FAQ mentions in a very understated way, "some people find `vi` difficult to use`.  (I say this as a long-time Vim user and the author of the FAQ entry in question.)

If you're stuck in the editor right now, you can quit by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> `:q!`.  Once you're out, you can pick an editor you like better.  If you're not sure which to use, try `nano` if it's available, which is designed to be easy to use.

The [Git FAQ explains how to set your editpr](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#configure-editor), but roughly, if you just want to set it for Git, you can run `git config core.editor 'nano'` (replacing `nano` with your preferred editor), and if you want to set the editor more globally, you should be able to run `nano ~/.bashrc` and then add the following line (replacing `nano` with your preferred editor):

```
export VISUAL="nano"
```

Then, if you run `exec bash`, Git and all other programs should start to use your preferred editor instead of vi.

Comment: Hmm. a) Thanks for the command to get me out of that hellhole! b) I'm pretty sure I set the editor to Notepad++ (double-checked: yes) c) I think my issue was that during the install I'd chosen MinTTY as a terminal emulator instead of Windows cmd.exe. Reinstalling Git with cmd.exe as the terminal window, and will report back if things improve.

Comment: Huh. Using CMD opens up Notepad++ when I request a commit. I'm almost certain I wrote my commit message in the terminal last time I tried using the terminal for Git. Go figure.

Comment: So - might go back to MinTTY and use your commands to switch the editor shortly, but things seem to be mostly working now! Will mark your answer as correct after I test positively!

Comment: It may be that the expected location of the configuration file is different in MingW64.  You can see what files are in use with `git config -l --show-origin`.